# Error in Travis: The job exceeded the maximum log length, and has been terminated

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, testing, travis-ci

I am running end to end test and found using .travis.yml

Below you can see my travis.yml
https://github.com/JosephThachilGeorge/TDDTEST/blob/master/.travis.yml

For goal : `- mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml verify -Pe2e`

I am getting error in Travis build:

> Travis: The job exceeded the maximum log length

However below goals are working perfectly:

- `mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml clean verify -Pjacoco coveralls:report`
- `mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report`
- `mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=JosephThachilGeorge_TDDTEST`
- `mvn -f spring-project/pom.xml verify -Pfailsafe`

My github link is : https://github.com/JosephThachilGeorge/TDDTEST

In Travis I am getting below huge build
and finally it says

> Travis: The job exceeded the maximum log length

[image]

Comment: Please specify your question. It's hard to tell exactly what you are looking others to provide.

Comment: I have found solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Following steps helped me to find solution :

suggests to create an src/test/resources/logback.xml (or log4j.properties if that’s the logging backend used but from the build log, that doesn’t seem likely) and lower the logging level for the necessary parts in it.

Looking at the logback.xml reference, the following logback.xml would lower the global logging level to INFO:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <root level="info"/>
</configuration>
```

As you can see in my build with this change 1, the log is now not being cluttered.